# Automatic calculator from datagridview or listview

Tags: c#, ms-access

I want to make a application let me show how it works.

| PRODUCT | STOCK | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| PHONE | 2000 | 10 |
| TEA | 3000 | 15 |
| CHICKEN | 3000 | 20 |

I'll write `textbox1.text` to 100 for example, the app gonna tell me you need 5 chickens for textbox1.text's value or 10 phones or 6 teas and 1 phone for let it equal 100.

I need to start search but i don't know where to start and keywords. I want to make a smart calculator (?)

Can you guys show me the way or algorithm ?

I'm pretty beginner at coding please be nice :)

I am trying to build a smart calculator and then looking for algorithm or pseudo code.

I've look for some giving changes tutorials, but i still dont know where to start. I'm still looking for it.

Comment: This looks to be a combinations and permeations question. With just those 3 choices, you have 200 possible outcomes.  This would thus suggest a recursive solution, and not particular easy. Do, you really want to spit out 200 answers here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you're working in Windows Forms, so you can bind your `textbox` event `OnTextChanged` to method that will automatically calculate things you need.

How to bind: select your textbox, then click "events" in right bottom of visual studio, place the mouse in the field right of "TextChanged", and click 2 times. A `private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` will automatically created at the Form1.cs file. Here you can write your logic to calculate things.